# Not getting any response from http post call even though status is 200

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http

I have an api of POST type. On sending a JSON body to that API, I would get some JSON response back. Below is screenshot of postman

[image]

Now I am trying to consume this API call and I wrote a simple HTTP post call and below is the code

```
 var itemdata = {
"terms": {
    "items": [
        {
            "_type": "term",
            "_id": "6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.1mdlmv35e.1618tt1.8mb4gb.nahef1pustcmu5k10omdh",
            "_url": "https://10.11.13.155:9445/ibm/iis/igc-rest/v1/assets/6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.1mdlmv35e.1618tt1.8mb4gb.nahef1pustcmu5k10omdh",
            "_name": "Export_01"
        }

    ]
}
};
  $http({
   method: 'POST',
    url: posturl,
    body : itemdata
})
.success(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
})
.error(function (error, status){
    console.log(error,status); 
});
```

But the issue is I am getting 200 for this, but I am not getting any response. Below is screenshot of browser network tab

[image]

Apart from this I don't see any error nor any response. What is the issue here? Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: see the response header `Content-Length: 0` - that's a clue why your result has no data - your request header ALSO has a `content-length: 0` - which suggests you aren't sending any POST data

Comment: @JaromandaX sry I have no idea.i didnt come across such issue before.What would be the fix here?

Comment: No iam sending data,if you see the code @JaromandaX

Comment: not according to the headers

Comment: @JaromandaX then do we need to add something in server side headers?